# Speed up C# native call pinvoke

Tags: c#, .net, interop, pinvoke

mod note: I do not believe this to be a duplicate, due to me having already tried several mentioned solutions as described below.

Is there a way I can speed this up? I've already followed the Microsoft guides on this, and here's what I've done:

1. Added SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity
2. Placed this in a file named UnsafeNativeMethods.cs
3. Defined specific types for the method stub

Here is the method:

```
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        [SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
        public static extern bool DeviceIoControl(
            IntPtr hDevice,
            uint IoControlCode,
            [In] MemoryManager.MemOperation InBuffer,
            int nInBufferSize,
            [Out] byte[] OutBuffer,
            uint nOutBufferSize,
            ref int pBytesReturned,
            IntPtr Overlapped
        );
```

Here is the contents of MemOperation (the inbuffer that has to be marshal'd I'm guessing):

```
        public struct MemOperation
        {
            public int Pid;
            public int UserPid;
            public int Size;
            public int protection_mode;
            public int allocation_type;
            public IntPtr Addr;
            public IntPtr WriteBuffer;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
            public string module_selection;
        }
```

Here's is an example of usage:

```
        public UnsafeNativeMethods.MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION QueryVirtualMemory(IntPtr address) {
            var memOperation = new MemOperation();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[48]; // 8 + 8 + 4 + 8 + 4 + 4 + 4 MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION
            memOperation.Pid = this.Pid;
            memOperation.Addr = address;
            int bytes = 0;
            bool res = UnsafeNativeMethods.DeviceIoControl(this.Handle, CtlCode(0x00000022, this.IOCTL_QUERY, 2, 0), memOperation, Marshal.SizeOf(memOperation), buffer, (uint)buffer.Length, ref bytes, IntPtr.Zero);
            return GetStructure<UnsafeNativeMethods.MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION>(buffer);
        }
```

In the profiler, my hotpath is the pinvoke. My application runs incredibly fast, as fast I think it can in C#. However, almost a third of all execution time is spent pinvoking due to how many memory operations the application is doing. I would like to cut this time down in any way possible, including unsafe ways.

I have seen that you can instead write a DeviceIoControl wrapper and import it from a C++ dll, however this did not lead to any changes for me, it appeared to function the exact same. Here's the source for  that:

devicecontrol.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "DeviceControl.h"

bool __cdecl DeviceIoRequestWrapper(HANDLE hDevice, DWORD dwIoControlCode, LPVOID lpInBuffer, DWORD nInBufferSize, LPVOID lpOutBuffer, DWORD nOutBufferSize, LPDWORD lpBytesReturned, LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlappedk)
{
    return DeviceIoControl(hDevice, dwIoControlCode, lpInBuffer, nInBufferSize, lpOutBuffer, nOutBufferSize, lpBytesReturned, lpOverlappedk);
}
```

devicecontrol.h

```
#pragma once

#include <Windows.h>

extern "C" {
    __declspec(dllexport) bool __cdecl DeviceIoRequestWrapper(
        HANDLE       hDevice,
        DWORD        dwIoControlCode,
        LPVOID       lpInBuffer,
        DWORD        nInBufferSize,
        LPVOID       lpOutBuffer,
        DWORD        nOutBufferSize,
        LPDWORD      lpBytesReturned,
        LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlappedk);
}
```

I am on .net 6.0 and the latest version of C#.

---

Proposed change to out buffer:

```
        public unsafe UnsafeNativeMethods.MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION QueryVirtualMemory(IntPtr address) {
            var memOperation = new MemOperation();
            byte* buffer = stackalloc byte[48];
            memOperation.Pid = this.Pid;
            memOperation.Addr = address;
            int bytes = 0;
            bool res = UnsafeNativeMethods.DeviceIoControl(this.Handle, CtlCode(0x00000022, this.IOCTL_QUERY, 2, 0), memOperation, Marshal.SizeOf(memOperation), (IntPtr)buffer, 48, ref bytes, IntPtr.Zero);
            return GetStructure<UnsafeNativeMethods.MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION>(buffer);
        }
```

Where GetStructure is now:

```
        public static unsafe T GetStructure<T>(byte* bytes) where T: unmanaged {
            T structure = *(T*)bytes;
            return structure;
        }
```

Comment: What does your calling pattern look like?  Do you call `UnsafeNativeMethods.DeviceIoControl` over and over again (say, for every member in a large collection).  My understanding of your comment _"my hotpath is the pinvoke"_ is that you call this a lot.  Two standard recommendations for hot P/Invoke are a) make every structure blittable (or as close as possible) to reduce copying/marshaling overhead (you seem close).  The other is to reduce API chattiness.  If you are going to call this 1000 times, marshal info for 1000 calls to the native later and do the 1000 calls there

Comment: Manual marshalling of the string `module_selection` and byte array `OutBuffer` should do the trick. You are also doing constant allocations of `buffer` is that really necessary

Comment: @Charlieface How would you want me to replace buffer? I've tried using a shared pool which led to BSODs for whatever reason, but the allocation of buffer doesn't seem to be too hot. It is listed as minor CPU usage (because the allocation of buffer zero's the memory out).

Comment: If you do custom marshalling then you can get an unmanaged pointer to a buffer. Keep that pointer and use unsafe code to zero it

Comment: @Charlieface Also, how would I manually marshal module_selection? Just change the signature to be an IntPtr (blittable I believe) and manually allocate it myself? Is there an unsafe way to do this in C# easily without copying memory (to avoid allocating a string and then converting it to a ptr) i.e. an equivalent to `wchar_t *t = L"MyString";` For manually marshalling the out buffer, I'd just change the signature to `[Out] void* OutBuffer,` and then use it as a byte array in an unsafe context?

Comment: @Charlieface Updated OP to show new version of buffer (not shared), just making sure I'm doing it right.

Comment: Are you sure it's the pinvoke overhead that is the bottleneck rather than the actual work in DeviceIoControl?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's what helped the most and I'll accept this as the answer to my own thread in a few hours.

In addition to the above steps I mentioned, I have now done the following:

1. Converted `MemOperation` to be fully blittable. The string "module_selection" was only ever used once per program start, so I have instead now added a fully blittable version of `MemOperation`. Thank you @Flydog57
2. Changed buffer to be quickly allocated (non zero'd out), and pass a PTR, rather than allocating and then marshalling a byte[] to void/char* (which is what I think likely happens when you pass it a byte[] object). Thank you @Charlieface

Running the profiler in visual studio, it appears to have eliminated the hotpath. Now the total CPU % correctly lies within kernel32.dll (the deviceiocontrol call to the device). Whether this leads to tangible performance benefits, I don't know, don't have an easy way to setup a full benchmark for this.